# SQL using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, pdo

There are 3 different filters: `books`, `authors` and `stores` (`select` lists), and I may use their all together at once or only one or two of them, so I use UNION to get together all queries

```
require('database.php');

$books_ids = $authors_ids = $stores_ids = [];

if(isset($_POST['books'])){
    $books_ids = $_POST["books"];
}
if(isset($_POST['authors'])){
    $authors_ids = $_POST["authors"];
}
if(isset($_POST['stores'])){
    $stores_ids = $_POST["stores"];
}

$query = "";

if( !empty( $books_ids ))
{
    $books_ids_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($books_ids), '?'));

    $query .= "SELECT
        b.id,
        b.`name`,
        b.`year`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.`name`) AS author_names,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.`name`) AS store_names,
        'book' as param
    FROM
        books AS b
        LEFT JOIN books_authors AS b_a ON b.id = b_a.book_id
        LEFT JOIN authors AS a ON a.id = b_a.author_id
        LEFT JOIN books_stores AS b_s ON b.id = b_s.book_id
        LEFT JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = b_s.store_id
    WHERE
        b.id IN (". $books_ids_in .")
    GROUP BY b.id";
}

if( !empty( $authors_ids ) )
{
    $authors_ids_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($authors_ids), '?'));

    if (!empty($query)) {
         $query .= " UNION ";
    }

    $query .= "SELECT
        b.id,
        b.`name`,
        b.`year`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.`name`) AS author_names,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.`name`) AS store_names,
        'author' as param
    FROM
        books AS b
        LEFT JOIN books_authors AS b_a ON b.id = b_a.book_id
        LEFT JOIN authors AS a ON a.id = b_a.author_id
        LEFT JOIN books_stores AS b_s ON b.id = b_s.book_id
        LEFT JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = b_s.store_id
    WHERE
        b.id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT book_id FROM books_authors WHERE author_id IN (". $authors_ids_in .")
            )
    GROUP BY b.id";
}

if( !empty( $stores_ids ) )
{
    $stores_ids_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($stores_ids), '?'));

    if (!empty($query)) {
         $query .= " UNION ";
    }

    $query .= "SELECT
        b.id,
        b.`name`,
        b.`year`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.`name`) AS author_names,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.`name`) AS store_names,
        'store' as param
    FROM
        books AS b
        LEFT JOIN books_authors AS b_a ON b.id = b_a.book_id
        LEFT JOIN authors AS a ON a.id = b_a.author_id
        LEFT JOIN books_stores AS b_s ON b.id = b_s.book_id
        LEFT JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = b_s.store_id
    WHERE
        b.id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT book_id FROM books_stores WHERE store_id IN (". $stores_ids_in .")
            )
    GROUP BY b.id";
}

if( !empty( $query )) {

    $query .= " ORDER BY b.id";

    $param_array = array_merge($books_ids, $authors_ids, $stores_ids);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute($param_array);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($results);
}

$conn = null;
```

if `$query` is not empty, I add `ORDER BY` at the end `$query .= " ORDER BY b.id";` and it works if I use only one filter, but If I use 2 or more filters,  the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message   
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1250 Table 'b' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list' in   C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\filter.php:102 Stack trace: #0   C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\filter.php(102): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\filter.php on line 102
```

if I try to add `ORDER BY b.id` at the end every part of `$query`

the other error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\filter.php:105 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\filter.php(105): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\filter.php on line 105
```

How to add 'ORDER BY' here ?

Comment: What do you mean by 2 filters?

Comment: I have 3 select lists #books, #authors, #stores and can choose something from 1, 2 or all 3 of them. Then I pass data (using AJAX) in code above.

Comment: You mean if it actually uses the union ?

Comment: Look, all code in my question.

Comment: Try aliasing b.id in each select -> b.id as id_to_order and then order by this column, tell me what happens

Comment: may you give me an example of using?

Comment: In each select, change SELECT b.id,... to: SELECT b.id as new_id,.... and change the order by to order by new_id

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, it works.